# Django + Redis: How to invalidate cache for just one specific element

Tags: django, image, caching, redis

In the site I'm working on users can submit images (avatars).

When users want to update their images, the uploaded images go to celery were they are be resized, optimized and some thumbnails are also generated.

Only after processing is that images are showed in the site.

I intend to use redis to cache images for a long time and when the process above get completed, I'd like to invalidate the cache just for the uploaded image.

I failed to find docs / tutorials the teach us how to achieve these.

Could someone please point me out some tutorials / docs that explain how to cache images as well as how to invalidate the cache just for a specific image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use solr-thumbnail package which does all of this including caching. Also you can define redis as the kvstore. [Docs here](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/settings.html)